# how to make conditional rendering for google-autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-maps, autocomplete

For the places autocomplete we had been using Algolia places. Since Algolia places will be sunset end of May 2022, I am looking for an alternative. Google autocomplete looks great as an alternative. Here is my simple piece of code in react typescript:

```
import Autocomplete from 'react-google-autocomplete'

<Autocomplete
    apiKey={'API_KEY'}
    style={{ width: '100%' }}
    onPlaceSelected={(place) => {
        console.log(place)
    }}
    options={{
        types: this.state.locationType === 0 ? ['country'] : ['(cities)'],
    }}
/>
```

What I am try to do is that types in `Autocomplete` should be either **country** or **cities** depending on the state `locationType`. The problem is that it doesn't change the types though the state `locationType` is get changed. Let's say initial state for `locationType` is 0 and it shows list of predictions for countries. But when the state `locationType` gets updated to 1 it still shows the list of predictions for countries not for the cities.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Fortunately, I was able to make it working in following way

```
```

Comment: `{this.state.locationType === LocationType.Country && (
 <Col xs={8}>
  <Autocomplete
   apiKey={'API_KEY'}
                        options={{
          types: ['country'],
   }}
   .........
  />
 </Col>
)}
{this.state.locationType === LocationType.City && (
 <Col xs={8}>
  <Autocomplete
   apiKey={'API_KEY'}
                         options={{
          types: ['(cities)'],
   }}
   .........
  />
 </Col>
)}`